# Put a set of characters into list in python

Tags: python

Essentially I want to put characters inside a list so I can make the for loop work.

Example characters (supposedly listed individually vertically. not like this showing as one line)
N/A
N/A
None
Test
Dev

I want to put these characters into a list like below
a = [N/A, N/A, None, Test, Dev]

Reason is when I use for loop into these characters (let's say there are all inside "test_report". For loop is not working because it is reading the "test_report" as like this:

```
N
/
A

N
/
A

N
o
n
e
```

```
count = 0
for i in test_report:
    if i == "Test":
         count += 1
return count
```

Comment: Can you give an example value for `test_report`?

Comment: Please, show the content of *test_report*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
with open('test_report.txt', 'r') as f:
    test_arr = f.read().split()

print(test_arr)
```

Considered your `test_report.txt` like this...

```
N/A
N/A
None
Test
Dev
```